# Pytest with Pycharm executing files that doesn't start with keyword "test"

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

[image: these are some of the other files under project .These are not executed by pytest]SeleniumPython is a project in Pycharm. there are 2 packages created under it. each package has 2 python files.

[image]

when I type `pytest` in the terminal window of Pycharm, the test methods inside file "system_test.py" and "functional_test.py" is executed. Why is Pycharm behaving like that? Ideally, it should execute files and methods starting with the keyword "Test".

"system_test.py", "system_test2.py", "functional_test.py" and "functional_test2.py" have 3 methods each starting with keyword "test".The files were actually created for running Unittest test cases and is as below

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner


class test_simple1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_method1(self):
        print("This is system test method 1")

    def test_method2(self):
        print("This is system test method 2")

    def test_method3(self):
        print("This is system test method 3")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="./Reports"))
```

Why is Pycharm considering the first 2 files in each of the packages and executing the methods inside them even though pytest is not imported in any of the files.

Comment: `pytest` discovers tests using `test_*.py` or `*_test.py`
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery

Comment: thanks for your reply . Actually there are other  python files under the project that starts with "Test_" but those are not executed .Only the tests under the 2 packages are executed. I will also attach the screen shot of other files in the project which are not executed

Comment: Check out the discovery rules in the link, pytest looks for lowercase `test_*.py or *_test.py` files.

Comment: I got your point . Thank you very much